# Why is this Javascript code printing different values for the same variable?

Tags: javascript

This peice of code is really confusing me:

```js
players = 5;
window["Kappa"] = 2;
if (players > 2)
  window["Kappa"] = 3;
document.write(Kappa);
document.write(Kappa);
```

As you can see it returns 23 even though it prints the same variable twice? Shouldn't it print 33 instead?

I get that `window['variable']` creates a new variable called variable, but I still can't work out why the same variable would output different things... Why would they even use `window` instead of `var` here?

Comment: they aren’t the same identifier — they just look like they are:

`[ ...'Kappa' ].map(char => char.codePointAt(0)) // [8490, 97, 112, 112, 97]`

Comment: I suggest you stop using global variables.

Comment: @AmericanSlime not my code :/

Comment: those two Kappa's are not the same although they look like the same. when i copied the codes and posted into a file opened with vi and searched Kappa and only the Kappa assigned the value 2 were matched.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Explanation

The reason 23 is output instead of 33 is because there are actually 2 `Kappa` variables. One of the `Kappa` variables starts with a **K** (U+004B) however the other `Kappa` starts with a **Kelvin K** (U+212A). Even though they are different characters, the font renders them both in the same way.

## Javascript Variables

Javascript variables can contain more than just ASCII characters. [This](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-identifiers) site gives an explanation on the allowed characters:

> An identifier must start with $, _, or any character in the Unicode
> categories “Uppercase letter (Lu)”, “Lowercase letter (Ll)”,
> “Titlecase letter (Lt)”, “Modifier letter (Lm)”, “Other letter (Lo)”,
> or “Letter number (Nl)”.
>
> The rest of the string can contain the same characters, plus any
> U+200C zero width non-joiner characters, U+200D zero width joiner
> characters, and characters in the Unicode categories “Non-spacing mark
> (Mn)”, “Spacing combining mark (Mc)”, “Decimal digit number (Nd)”, or
> “Connector punctuation (Pc)”.

Javascript only looks at the character codes in the identifier, not at how the identifier is rendered. That's why these 2 variables are considered different by Javascript.